# WPF ListView multiple ItemContainerStyles

Tags: wpf, itemcontainerstyle

This is my WPF ListView which works fine.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ItemContStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Key1" Color="#f7fcfe" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Key2" Color="#fff1cf" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Key3" Color="#fdeff2" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style></Window.Resources>

<ListView 
 Name="UserLst" Width="320"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}">                        
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Style>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        <GridViewColumn Header="id" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_id}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="UserID" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_UserID}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Now I'm trying to add a function which detects left clicks on selected item as follows:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
</Style></ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I can't add this because there's already

```
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}"
```

in the ListView code.
I've been wondering if someone shed some light for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**BasedOn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) to inherit from above style:

```
<ListView Name="UserLst" Width="320">                        
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}">
         <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"     
                      Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   ......
</ListView>
```

This way you will get setters, triggers from above style and you can provide your own as well specific to your ListView. *(like EventSetter in your case)*

Comment: This works very fine! I really appreciate your quick reply and clear solution. Thank you so much!